# Add a Path to my Laravel Project for Blog

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, laravel-5, vhosts

I've hosted my Laravel Project through Apache2, linux server (Ubuntu 18.04) by doing necessary settings in my project and vhosts file, as recommended.

As for the blog, it is on wordpress and until now, it was hosted on wordpress server. I know how to host WP on my own server, through apache as well. If I wanted to host it as `blog.mydomain.com`, I would have had no problem and hosted it already. What I want for the blog is that it should be a part of my current domain and get hosted as "`mydomain.com/blog`".

So, my question is can someone guide me step by step through the process so I can host it as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved in apache using an alias.
Add below entry in your apache configuration.

```
Alias "/blog/" "/path/to/your/blog/"
```

More info: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html